# OmniWeb cannot load any URLs

Tags: macos

I installed OmniWeb this morning on my MacBook Pro (running Yosemite - up-to-date).

The other browsers I have installed (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari) all work like champs.

OmniWeb, on the other hand, cannot load any URLs - not even http://omnigroup.com.

The forum posts I found are related to test builds and/or from last year.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kcase on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/kcase/status/636289442869702656) answered this for me: the stable build is 5, the testing build is 6.

5 doesn't work on OS X >10.8.

Yosemite is 10.10, and requires the testing build.